# How do I find out what image is running in a Kubernetes VM on GCE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I've created a Kubernetes cluster in Google Compute Engine using `cluster/kube-up.sh`. How can I find out what Linux image GCE used to create the virtual machines? I've logged into some nodes using SSH and the usual commands (`uname -a` etc) don't tell me.

The default config file at `kubernetes/cluster/gce/config-default.sh` doesn't seem to offer any clues.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to look at it

1. In the Kubernetes GUI based dashboard, click on the nodes
2. From command line of the kubernetes master node use `kubectl describe
   pods/{pod-name}`

(Make sure to select the correct namespace, if you are using any.)

Here is a sample output, please look into the "image" label of the output

```
kubectl describe pods/fedoraapache
Name:                fedoraapache
Namespace:            default
Image(s):            fedora/apache
Node:                127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1
Labels:                name=fedoraapache
Status:                Running
Reason:
Message:
IP:                172.17.0.2
Replication Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  fedoraapache:
    Image:        fedora/apache
    State:        Running
      Started:        Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:37 -0400
    Ready:        True
    Restart Count:    0
Conditions:
  Type        Status
  Ready     True
Events:
  FirstSeen                LastSeen            Count    From            SubobjectPath                Reason        Message
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:35 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:35 -0400    1    {scheduler }                            scheduled    Successfully assigned fedoraapache to 127.0.0.1
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:35 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:35 -0400    1    {kubelet 127.0.0.1}    implicitly required container POD    pulled        Pod container image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:36 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:36 -0400    1    {kubelet 127.0.0.1}    implicitly required container POD    created        Created with docker id 98aeb13c657b
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:36 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:36 -0400    1    {kubelet 127.0.0.1}    implicitly required container POD    started        Started with docker id 98aeb13c657b
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:37 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:37 -0400    1    {kubelet 127.0.0.1}    spec.containers{fedoraapache}        created        Created with docker id debe7fe1ff4f
  Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:37 -0400    Thu, 06 Aug 2015 03:38:37 -0400    1    {kubelet 127.0.0.1}    spec.containers{fedoraapache}        started        Started with docker id debe7fe1ff4f
```

Comment: Thanks. This command reveals 'Image: nginx'. How can I find out more about what distro is in that image (presuming that is the image details)?

Comment: look for the image name in the description.. added a sample output

Answer (score 0):

It uses something called Google Container VM image. Check out the blogpost announcing it here:

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/introducing-Google-Container-VM-Image.html